# Como puedo evitar Registro Duplicado en MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

estoy tratando de hace una validaciòn de evitar que el usuario o los usuarios eviten registrar dobles Correos es decir que los datos de correo en la tabla de usuario dentro de MYSQL PHPMYADMIN no se repita, mi còdigo es el siguiente

```html
<?php
 require_once "Conexion.php";
 require_once "UsuarioFotoDocumento.php";

 $obj=new documento();

 $datos=array();

 /*--EN ESTA PARTE SE AGREGA EL POSTEO DE LA IMAGEN QUE SOLO ALMACENA LA DIRECCION DE LA CARPETA*/
 $nombreImg=$_FILES['imagedoc']['name'];
 $RutaAlmacenamiento=$_FILES['imagedoc']['tmp_name'];
 $carpeta='../../archivos/';
 $RutaFinal=$carpeta.md5(rand() * time()).$nombreImg;
 /*--Y SE GUARDA, DECLARANDO INICIO DE LA RUTA Y FINAL DE LA MISMA CREANDO UNA CARPETA ARCHIVOS*/
  
$datosImg=array(
  $_POST['iTipDocIdent'],
  $nombreImg,
  $RutaFinal
    );

  if (move_uploaded_file($RutaAlmacenamiento, $RutaFinal)) {
   $idimagen=$obj->agregarImagenDoc($datosImg);

   if (buscaRepetido( $datos[1],$conexion) == 1) {
    echo 2;
   }else {
   if ($idimagen > 0) {

    $datos[0]=$_POST['iCodOrdenante'];
    $datos[1]=$_POST['vEmailUsuario'];
    $datos[2]=sha1($_POST['vPassUsuario']);
    $datos[3]=$_POST['iTipDocIdent'];
    $datos[4]=$idimagen;

     echo $obj->insertarUsuarioNuevo($datos);
    }else {
     echo 0;
    }    
   }
  }

  function buscaRepetido($email,$conexion){
   $sql="SELECT * from tbl1_usuario
        where vEmailUsuario='$email'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            return 1;
           }else{
            return 0;
           }        
  }
?>
```

estoy usando un **AJAX** donde se debe registrar los datos màs una imagen en mi funcion ajax me declina a error y eso es por el arreglo ya que antes de poner la funcion de **buscaRepetidos** me registraba los datos y la imagen normal sin problemas, alguien sabe si el orden de la funcion està afectando al arreglo por lo cual no registra, en mi archivo de arreglo son 2 el primero es el que estàlìneas arribla y el segundo es para recojer los datos y almacenarlos en variables de arreglo de datos por row es decir $dato[0] ya que haci puedo registrar en mis dos tablas una que es tabla de registro de usuario y la otra tabla de imagen del usuario en donde ambas tablas se relacionan por el ID_IMAGEN de usuario 
dejo mi segundo arreglo que va de la mano con el arreglo de agregarUsuario

```html
<?php 
 class documento{
  public function agregarImagenDoc($datos){
   $c=new conectar ();
   $conexion=$c->conexion();

   $fecha=date('Y-m-d');

   $sql="INSERT into tbl4_img_cliente (id_iTipDocIdent,
              Nombre_Img,
              Ruta_Img,
              fechaSubida)
              values ('$datos[0]',
                '$datos[1]',
                '$datos[2]',
                '$fecha')";

   $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

   return mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
  }

  public function insertarUsuarioNuevo($datos){
   $c=new conectar ();
   $conexion=$c->conexion();

   $sql="INSERT into tbl1_usuario (iCodOrdenanteCli,
               vEmailUsuario,
               vPassUsuario,
               iTipDocIdent,
               vFotoCliente_ID)
        values ('$datos[0]',
          '$datos[1]',
          '$datos[2]',
          '$datos[3]',
          '$datos[4]'";   

   return mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);          
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Por ultima este es mi codigo AJAX por si las dudas aqui es donde los datos y la iamgen pasan por MULTIPART

```js
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("User_Form_Reg"));

    $.ajax({
     url: "AgregarNuevoUsuario.php",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "html",
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,

     success:function(r){
      
            if (r==2){
            alert.('Correo repetido');
            }
      elseif(r == 1){
       alert.('Registro Exitoso');
       $('#User_Form_Reg')[0].reset();
      }else{
       alert.('Error');
       return false;
      }
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Una buena practica es crear un indice único para el correo de los usuarios que se pretenden registrar, te dejo un ejemplo create de la tabla en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `rol` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
    `remember_token` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
```

Si te fijas en esta línea es donde se agrega:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
```

De esta manera al intentar agregar un correo que ya existe te arrojaría un error.

Comment: Adhiero esta sería la mejor manera ya que de NINGUNA manera podría existir un registro con el email repetido, lo único que faltaría es a través de PHP capturar la excepción o el error y exhibirlo al usuario de "buena" manera.

Answer (score 0):

La opción de Eduardo Díaz sería la mejorcita, pero también podrías utilizar un SELECT que te busque el correo en la tabla y si te arroja un registro, envías un mensaje de error y no haces el INSERT, del contrario, ejecutas el INSERT te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$correo = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl1_usuario WHERE 
correo='$datos[*correo*]'"));
if($correo==0){
*código del INSERT*
}else{
echo 'Ya existe un usuario registrado a este correo';
}
```

Existen muchas formas de hacer las cosas, como ya dije, Eduardo Días dió una mejor alternativa, pero te dejo aquí otra forma.